# unzip files are not in exact format

Tags: java, unzip, zipinputstream

i want to unzip all the folders and different kind of files like .xls,.apk,.png etc.But while extracting all the files are their in newly extracted foder(or folders under that folder). but those .xml,.png ,.apk files are not in proper format. when i open ,xls file it shows a pop that format may be different and also when it opens that files all the content is in different format. .png files are also not able to open, neither .apk are useful after extracting. why it is happening ?? 
**

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class UnzipFiles {

    public static void main(String a[]){

        UnzipFiles mfe = new UnzipFiles();
        mfe.unzipFile("E:/New folder/pics.zip");
    }
    public void unzipFile(String filePath){

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ZipInputStream zipIs = null;
        ZipEntry zEntry = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            zipIs = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
            while((zEntry = zipIs.getNextEntry()) != null){
                try{
                    byte[] tmp = new byte[25*1024*1024];
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    /*String opFilePath = "E:/New folder/new/"+zEntry.getName();*/
                   String opFilePath= "E:/New folder/new"+File.separator+zEntry.getName();
                    File f = new File(  opFilePath); 
                    if(zEntry.isDirectory())
                    { f.mkdirs();
                    System.out.println(f.getName()+"   "+"folder created");
                    }

                    else{
                    System.out.println(f.getName());
                    /*System.out.println("Extracting file to "+opFilePath);*/
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    BufferedOutputStream out =  new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                    int size = 0;
                    int k= zipIs.read(tmp);
                    System.out.println(k+1);
                    while((size = zipIs.read(tmp)) != -1){
                        out.write(tmp, 0 , size);

                    }

                    }

                } catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            zipIs.closeEntry();
            zipIs.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

**

Comment: "i want to unzip all the folders" it means zipped file contain lots of folders and those folder contains different kind of files. i think unzipped files have different format/unicode

Comment: @ fge can you please elaborate it. i am novice to java, m  not able to understand your comment  please explain in broader sense.

Comment: int k= zipIs.read(tmp);   i used to check what this function is returning. i dont think this line is have any meaning in this code

Comment: if i remove these 2 lines than it is working fine for png files. but still problem exist for other file like text file and other file

Comment: and the size of the unzipped files is less by 3 ,4 kb than the original file. suppose one text file is of 10 kb and in zipped format it is of 6 kb but after unzipping its size is 9 kb , not 10 kb.

Comment: solved!!   i forgot to use   close buffered output stream

Comment: how to modify it so that it can work with all the zipped format like  .zip , .rar , .7z

Answer (score 2):

You forget to put the first bytes you read into the destination file:

```
                int k= zipIs.read(tmp); // <--- HERE
                System.out.println(k+1);
                while((size = zipIs.read(tmp)) != -1){
                    out.write(tmp, 0 , size);
```

---

Also, if you use Java 7, use a ZIP `FileSystem` instead, along with `Files.walkFileTree()`; that will make your job *much* more simple!